# Node.js deep merge (but clone) into this

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, merge, deep-copy

In the constructor of my class, I would like to merge an existing object into `this`. The operation needs to merge deeply (i.e. recursively) and clone the source object's fields (and not assign them). It's like cloning, except into an existing object.

I have tried the npm package `merge`, but making changes to `this` also affects the source object (indicating that it's been merged by assigning, not cloning). The package `clone` creates an entirely new object so can't be used with `this`. `Object.assign` does not clone. I'm not sure what else to try. Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

When using `merge`, I can change a top-level field of `this` without affecting the source object, but not something within a top-level object field. Oh and yes, I'm using `merge.recursive`.

Comment: *I'm using merge.recursive* - nobody but you knows how you use it. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and may be closed. You can use `merge` or `extend`, both have deep clone mode.

Comment: Ok I'll add some more detail asap, @estus